# Car battery drain issue with Clock ON

Tags: car, battery-drain

I had the issue of the battery going dead in 12-13 days if my car(Chevy Beat LT) sits idle for that long. An idle current measured was 0.16A that gives around 13days to my 50AH battery. After removing the fuse(3 legged yellow fuse) for "Clock/Remote Keyless Entry/Radio" drain current went down to 9mA. Now I don't have the issue of the battery going dead but now Odometer is not working, cant see the fuel level or anything as the display is OFF.

There was another fuse labelled "Remote Keyless Entry/Radio", but removing it did not help. So now I plug the fuse when I drive and remove the fuse when the car is going to be parked for long.

Any suggestions regarding the long term solution with be of great help.

Comment: Has someone incorrectly wired the radio so it is permanently on? Or have they added some aftermarket accessories that are draining the battery? A clock - even the old mechanical clocks would not cause that amount of drain...

Comment: If the car sits for long periods, get a [battery tender](http://products.batterytender.com/Chargers/) for those periods. It will save your battery as well as your sanity. The "Jr" version is relatively inexpensive (you can find it cheaper than what's on the manufacturer's page) and would provide up to a .75A charge, which is more than enough to overcome the draw.